# SBT tests [info] Passed: Total 0, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 0

Tags: testing, junit, sbt

With sbt build, Java Play, my tests are ignored when I type: sbt->compile->test. The message I get is:

```
[info] Passed: Total 0, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 0
```

although I have 26 tests.

Dependencies are these:

```scala
"org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.9.5" % "test",
"org.hamcrest" % "hamcrest-all" % "1.3" % "test",
```

Comment: Where is your test code? Unit test source must be under `src/test/scala` in order to be found by `sbt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had "testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument("junitxml", "console")" in build.sbt. That caused the tests to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're using JUnit (because you're using hamcrest).

You need to add junit-interface to run JUnit tests. So, add the junit interface to your dependencies, in your build.sbt file.

`libraryDependencies += "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % "test"`

This is documented in [sbt Reference Manual - Testing](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Testing.html) and [github.com/sbt/junit-interface](https://github.com/sbt/junit-interface)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Matthew. I tried adding the interface dependency - does not help.